# Aligning side-by-side tables with blank lines

Tags: tables

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to produce side-by-side tables that look like this:

[image]

except that the left-hand table should have completely blank lines instead of the two vertical lines in every other row. I tried this:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.1}\\\hline
k & t_k & u_k & f(t_k,u_k) \\\hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\\hline\\\hline
1 & 0.1 & 1.8 & -1.7 \\\hline \\\hline
2 & 0.2 & 1.63 & -1.43 \\\hline \\\hline
3 & 0.3 & 1.487 & -1.187 \\\hline \\\hline
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.05}\\\hline
k & t_k & u_k & f(t_k,u_k) \\\hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\\hline
1 & 0.05 & 1.9 & -1.85 \\\hline
2 & 0.1 & 1.808 & -1.708 \\\hline 
3 & 0.15 & 1.722 & -1.572 \\\hline
4 & 0.2 & 1.644 & -1.444 \\\hline
5 & 0.25 & 1.571 & -1.321 \\\hline
6 & 0.3 & 1.505 & -1.205 \\\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

which produced the output above. Is there an easy way to do what I want? (I'm using the `array` and `multirow` packages).

Comment: In the particular multicolumns, use {|c} instead of {|c|}, instead of a double hline

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if you want to turn that into an answer, I'll accept that one since you were first; otherwise I'll accept Gonzalo's answer below. Either way, thank you.

Comment: Gonzalo did the work, give it to him.  Cheers!

Comment: Your code, when augmented to form a minimum working example (MWE), doesn't generate the image that's currently posted; it also features, in the first `array` environment, a row of `| |` followed by a horizontal black line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to override the declared format; I also used `t` for the optional argument of array to produce top alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}[t]{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.1} \\
\hline
k & t_k & u_k & f(t_k,u_k) \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
\hline
1 & 0.1 & 1.8 & -1.7 \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
\hline
2 & 0.2 & 1.63 & -1.43 \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
\hline
3 & 0.3 & 1.487 & -1.187 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.05} \\
\hline
k & t_k & u_k & f(t_k,u_k) \\    \hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\    \hline
1 & 0.05 & 1.9 & -1.85 \\    \hline
2 & 0.1 & 1.808 & -1.708 \\    \hline 
3 & 0.15 & 1.722 & -1.572 \\    \hline
4 & 0.2 & 1.644 & -1.444 \\    \hline
5 & 0.25 & 1.571 & -1.321 \\    \hline
6 & 0.3 & 1.505 & -1.205 \\    \hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have an unneeded `\\\hline` statement at the end of the first `array`. If you leave out this statement, the two arrays will be aligned correctly.

If you want to go a bit further, I'd recommend you use the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type to align the numbers on their decimal points. And, as already shown in Gonzalo Medina's answer, you may want to insert `\multicolumn{1}{c}{ }` directives in the first table to suppress (presumably unnecessary) `| |` in every other row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=2.3}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{| l | S | S | S |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.1}\\ \hline
k & {t_k} & {u_k} & {f(t_k,u_k)} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2          \\\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }\\\hline % extra blank line
1 & 0.1 & 1.8 & -1.7    \\\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }\\\hline % extra blank line
2 & 0.2 & 1.63 & -1.43  \\\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }\\\hline % extra blank line
3 & 0.3 & 1.487 & -1.187\\\hline 
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{| l | S | S | S |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\Delta t = 0.05}\\ \hline
k & {t_k} & {u_k} & {f(t_k,u_k)} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\\hline
1 & 0.05 & 1.9 & -1.85 \\\hline
2 & 0.1 & 1.808 & -1.708 \\\hline 
3 & 0.15 & 1.722 & -1.572 \\\hline
4 & 0.2 & 1.644 & -1.444 \\\hline
5 & 0.25 & 1.571 & -1.321 \\\hline
6 & 0.3 & 1.505 & -1.205 \\\hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

I'd also like to encourage you to consider getting rid of all vertical lines; they really don't add any useful information once the numeric columns are aligned on the decimal points. As a bonus, you needn't type something like `\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } \\` to generate a blank line without vertical lines; `\\` is enough. :-)  Moreover, I'd argue that most horizontal lines in the two arrays aren't needed either.

Here, then, is a slight modification of your example; instead of `\hline`, it uses the `booktabs` package (and its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`) to draw horizontal lines with better spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=2.3}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ @{} l  S  S  S @{} }
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\Delta t = 0.1}\\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
k & {t_k} & {u_k} & {f(t_k,u_k)} \\ 
\midrule
0 & 0 & 2 & -2          \\ \\ % extra blank line
1 & 0.1 & 1.8 & -1.7    \\ \\ % extra blank line
2 & 0.2 & 1.63 & -1.43  \\ \\ % extra blank line
3 & 0.3 & 1.487 & -1.187\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ @{} l  S  S  S @{} }
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\Delta t = 0.05}\\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
k & {t_k} & {u_k} & {f(t_k,u_k)} \\ 
\midrule
0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\
1 & 0.05 & 1.9 & -1.85 \\
2 & 0.1 & 1.808 & -1.708 \\ 
3 & 0.15 & 1.722 & -1.572 \\
4 & 0.2 & 1.644 & -1.444 \\
5 & 0.25 & 1.571 & -1.321 \\
6 & 0.3 & 1.505 & -1.205 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The added `@{}` contradict somehow the introduced vertical padding introduces by `booktabs`’ rules. It looks like the `k` column is about to fall down the rule’s edge.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - The default extra whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the last column of an `array` is given by `\arraycolsep` (usually, `6pt`). Omitting this extra whitespace via `@{}` directives is something that the author of the `booktabs` package seems to recommend doing. In the present example, it may be that because the first column is quite thin, some extra padding (i.e., extra whitespace) may indeed counteract the effect you describe. However, I wouldn't leave off `@{}` entirely; instead, I'd insert something like `@{\hspace*{2pt}}`.

Comment: Yes, this isn’t new to me. :) While I agree on most things in the `booktabs` manual, this is something that doesn’t look right *to me*, especially due to the added vertical space. It’s like protrusion pushing certain glyphs into the margin. Here the rules protrude. And, yes it helps that the first column is very thin. The effect isn’t that big on the other side because the header is wider than the rest and the `)` glyph has more white space on the right than `$k$` on the left. Anyway, to each its own. (Nonetheless, this does produce a better output as a `|`-`\hline` solution!)

Comment: Is it possible to add caption to them?

Comment: @alper - Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: The best way to proceed strongly depends on your tables. Are they exactly like the ones above? (That would appear to be a low-probability event...) Please consider posting a new query, which will achieve far for visibility than any add-on to a 10-year-old posting.